# Programmatically set page_on_front

Tags: frontpage

I am trying to programmatically set the 'page_on_front' option with the id value retrieved from the get_page_by_title command...

```
$homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page' );
update_option('page_on_front', $homepage);
update_option('show_on_front', 'page');
```

This isn't working, can anyone help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`get_page_by_title()` returns an object.

Use `$homepage->ID`.

You should also check if you really got a usable return value:

```
$homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Front Page' );

if ( $homepage )
{
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```