# Set static page as default front page on newly created sites in multisite

Tags: multisite, frontpage, customization

How to set a Static page (example Sample Page with every WordPress install) as default fron page for every newly created site on multisite network. I mean when a new user creates a site on my multisite network a Page with custom name sets as front page automatically. Please tell me how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Based on these two Q&A's (not tested):

- [How to add Custom Blog Options to new blog setup form?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/50235/12615)
- [Programmatically set page_on_front](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/96066/12615)

```
add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'process_extra_field_on_blog_signup', 10, 6 );

function process_extra_field_on_blog_signup( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta ) {
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    $homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Sample Page' );   
    if ( $homepage )
    {
        update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
        update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Use it as a [Must Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides a function [update_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/) to set static page programmatically by default when a new blog is created in network multisite.

```
function my_new_blog_settings($blog_id, $user_id) {

    // set static front page in general settings
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page', true);

    // set the static page based on page ID 
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $page_id, true);
}
```

Above given code can be invoked using action 'wpmu_new_blog'

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'my_new_blog_settings', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, wpmu_new_blog is deprecated. Use wp_insert_site instead. To give a proper overview, the question can now be answered as follow:

```
function process_extra_field_on_blog_signup( $new_site ) {
    $blog_id = $new_site->blog_id;
    switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    $homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Sample Page' );   
    if ( $homepage )
{
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
    update_blog_option( $blog_id, 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
restore_current_blog();

}
add_action( 'wp_insert_site', 'process_extra_field_on_blog_signup', 10, 6 );
```

Answer (score -1):

1) To set Your first page you can add new page as `home.php` in your directory. Wordpress by default take `home.php` as its first page if it is declared.

2) Go to settings->Reading->Front page display. You can set here your front page which will display when your site open.