# The Events Calendar: Events page as Home page

Tags: multisite, the-events-calendar

I have a WordPress Multisite and I use the The Events Calendar plugin

I want to set the "Events page" as the default "Home page". For example:

`subdomain.domain/site1/events/` as default Home page in `subdomain.domain/site1/`
`subdomain.domain/site2/events/` as default Home page in `subdomain.domain/site2/`

Or, apply an automatic redirect? Using`.htaccess`? What is the code to redirect every site?

`subdomain.domain/site1` redirect to `subdomain.domain/site1/events`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the code from this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96068/10

```
$homepage = get_page_by_title( 'Events' );

if ( $homepage )
{
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

Haven't tested it with multisite, but my guess is that it should work as advertised.