# How to change a post attribute to homepage using WP CLI?

Tags: wp-cli, command-line

I want to convert a page to homepage. To add widget to homepage I need to do that. How will I be able to do that using WP CLI?

Comment: Do you mean the site's static front page, or the site's blog posts page?

Comment: I mean the static front page

Answer (score 3):

To set the site's static home page with WP-CLI, you should be able to do something like this:

```
wp option update show_on_front "page"
wp option update page_on_front {$page_id}
```

... where {$page_id} is the ID of the page you want to be the front page.

(Your question was originally tagged `multisite`—if you're running a Multisite installation, and want to specify a site other than the main site, you'll need to do this:

```
wp option update show_on_front "page" --url=example.com/site
wp option update page_on_front {$page_id} --url=example.com/site
```

... where `example.com/site` is the URL of the site you wish to affect.)

**Note:** I haven't tested this code. You should try it on a non-production WordPress installation first to be sure it works as intended.

### References

- [`wp option update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/)
- [A related answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96068/16121) with the required option names (`show_on_front` & `page_on_front`)